# Set Text with textmesh pro

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to cycle text with textmesh script?

I'm interested in cycling text so i can display different text on my 2D game.

I have try the script on [this website](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/ScriptReference/TextMeshPro-SetText.html). But I don't think it works. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class CyclingText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text text;
    void Update()
    {
        TextMeshPro textmeshPro = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        textmeshPro.SetText("The first number is {0} and the 2nd is {1:2} and the 3rd is {3:0}.", 4, 6.345f, 3.5f);
        // The text displayed will be:
        // The first number is 4 and the 2nd is 6.35 and the 3rd is 4.
    }   
}
```

Can someone provide me with an answer or explained what I done wrong?

Comment: what is happening? What is not working?

Answer (score 5):

You seem a bit confused about the use of `TMP`

**1**

If you set the TMP in the inspector as public you can simply

```
public TMP_text text;
```

And then drag the text inside the inspector and simply:

```
text.text = "Text displayed";
```

**2**

If you don't create a public variable but a private, you can:

```
private TMP_text text;
```

And then, if your script is in the text object you can:

```
text = this.gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
```

And

```
text.text = "Your text";
```

Comment: Seems not to be what OP is asking though ;) This is the usage of components in general but OP wants to cycle the text I guess like a dynamic banner kind of

Comment: @derHugo I see, but his problem and code wasn't related to cycling the text, so I solve his first confusion

Comment: Like the comments said the text displayed will be: The first number is 4 and the 2nd is 6.35 and the 3rd is 4. When I applied to a empty game object. It didn't seem to do anything. And it also give me a NullReferenceException on line 11. So I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @derHugo Dynamic banner? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Joker-tec if you don't know I don't either ^^ I just assumed that by `cycling` text you mean something like at first you only see `Hello ` then `ello W` then `llo Wo` etc .. like a dynamic banner where the text passes through from one side to the other ^^

Comment: @Joker-tec just check the TMP document, if you have problems in the implementation https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-textmesh-pro